# Should all my Python modules be explicitly importing the same base modules?

Tags: python, performance, memory, import

For example:
main.py:

```
import pygame
import mycolors
color1 = mycolors.blue
```

mycolors.py:

```
import pygame
blue = pygame.Color(0, 0, 255)
```

My question specifically concerns the "import pygame" present in both files.  Is it really necessary to import it within each module that requires it? (answer seem to be yes, it won't run without it.)  Also, does this actually get imported twice? does this have performance ramifications?

Comment: Is that all that is in main.py? You shouldn't need to import pygame there if that is the case

Comment: no I am sorry, I was just writing up some sample code to spare you the brunt of needless reading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module is only imported once, so you don't have to worry about wasted resources. You can see all the modules that have been imported anywhere in `sys.modules`. When the module is imported the second/third/etc. time you just get a reference to the module already in `sys.modules`

The reason you have to import it into both of the other modules is that it gets added to their namespace

This is very important in larger programs when there may be lots of modules with the same name, so you definitely wouldn't want a module to pop up in every other namespace whenever you imported it

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by your last paragraph? How does `main.py` benefit from importing `pygame`?

Comment: @Tim, One example would be if you have a bunch of packages that all store load their config from their respective `config.py`. This is why a global import system would be really bad.

Comment: @Tim, pygame isn't used in the snippet of main.py shown here. I thought there must be more code that wasn't included

Answer (score 2):

I don't think these are the entire source files you're showing here. As they are now, `import pygame` is not necessary in `main.py` since you're not referencing it anywhere in that module.

As for performance: It's not going to hurt perceptibly to import the same module several times. The "real" import (with the possible compilation step) happens only once.